# Firestore onSnapshot promise do not resolve

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm fighting with firebase functions for few days and today i started this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/firebase-emulator. However at 16th step there is something like this:

```
await new Promise((resolve) => {
  const unsubscribe = aliceCartRef.onSnapshot(snap => {
    const expectedCount = 2;
    const expectedTotal = 9.98;
    
    console.log(snap.data());
    if (snap.data().itemCount === expectedCount && snap.data().totalPrice == expectedTotal) {
      console.log("We're in if!");
      unsubscribe();
      console.log("After subscribe!");
      resolve();
      console.log("After resolve!");
    };
  });
});
```

I've put console.log by my self and discovered that onSnap function runs twice. For the first time snap object looks like this: { totalPrice: 0, itemCount: 0, ownerUID: 'alice' } and it do not pass if condition. On the second time snap is { ownerUID: 'alice', totalPrice: 9.98, itemCount: 2 } so it passes if condition but resolve() do not close Promise. Finally test fails every time because of timeout.

Why resolve() do not work in the second call?

Answer (score 0):

resolve() only call once. You can use the second call. I think you should get all data before resolve().
For example:

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
        var cities = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            cities.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing non-whole numbers like this is always dangerous:

```
snap.data().totalPrice == expectedTotal /* 9.98 */
```

JavaScript (and most environments) store such non-whole numbers as so-called floating point numbers, and those have an unreliable precision that makes them very hard to compare with `==`.

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but you can quickly test if it is by using a range comparison:

```
snap.data().totalPrice > 9.97 && snap.data().totalPrice < 9.99
```

---

If that indeed proves to solve the problem, consider storing the amounts in whole increments of a smaller unit. For example instead of storing 9 dollars and 98 cents, storing it as 998 dollar cents, so that the comparison becomes:

```
snap.data().totalPrice === 998
```

Whole numbers are stored differently and don't have the same precision problem that floating point numbers have.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replies. However problem lied in another place. The lambda function that wraps code had parameter "done" which was the reason of not finishing the function. That's why test do not pass. My mistake. But [codelabs that google is sharing](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/firebase-emulator#15) have some broken code :(